# Any better way to install material/paper elements in polymer 3

Tags: npm, polymer-3.x

for installation of any material elements in webcomponents/MWC components., currently iam using

```
npm install --save @polymer/paper-input
npm install --save @polymer/paper-button
```

etc.

Same goes for MWC of polymer 3 as well.

> Is there any better way to install all paper elements.

I tried `npm install --save @polymer/paper-elements`

it is creating different node module structure with no js files imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems old school method is the only solution I came across so far.

in `package.json`., under `dependencies` define all required dependencies and call `npm install`

```
"dependencies": {

"@polymer/paper-button": "^3.0.1",
"@polymer/paper-dialog": "^3.0.1",
"@polymer/paper-icon-button": "^3.0.2",
"@polymer/paper-input": "^3.0.1",
"@polymer/polymer": "^3.0.0",
  }
```